# Ajax post returning bad request for only one record

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamics-crm-2011

On load of one of my forms in CRM 2011 i am using an ajax post to clear some fields. On most records it is fine but on one it is failing each time and I cannot figure out what is different with this one that would be causing it to fail. Can someone look over the call i am making to see if there are any errors with it?

Thanks

```
var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl().toString();
    var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
    var crmEntity = new Object();
    var ODATA_EntityCollection = "/SalesOrderSet";

    crmEntity.ts_payment_data = null;
    crmEntity.ts_payment_split = null;

    var jsonEntity = window.JSON.stringify(crmEntity);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        async: true,
        url: serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + ODATA_EntityCollection + "(guid'" + orderid + "')",
        data: jsonEntity,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("ClearPaymentData\nStatus: " + textStatus + "; ErrorThrown: " + errorThrown + "; Response: " + xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You no need to specify `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")`

when you specify `dataType:"json"`

Also note that `dataType is case sensitive`, hence not datatype

Answer (score 0):

We've found out what the issue was, turns out that one of the fields contained an unsupported character, in this case a long dash, so the ajax call was failing when retrieving it.

Thanks for your assistance